# 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>, mail not sent

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, thunderbird

I know, there is already an answer to this smtp-status, but sorry: i don't get it. A Customer of mine sends a big amount of mails and some can't be send cause of:

```
This is the mail system at host mailserver.blabla.local.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<mail@domain.de>: host mail.hostingserver.de[ip] said: 354 End data
    with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

More information:

```
Final-Recipient: acc1; mail@domain.de
Original-Recipient: acc1;info@domain.de
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.hostingserver.de
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

Return-Path: <sender@domain.de>
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by neptun.migra-mv.local (Postfix) with ESMTP id 071A07418E6;
    Thu,  3 Nov 2016 12:04:22 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: by amavisd-new-2.10.1 (20141025) (Debian) at migra-mv.local
Received: from mailserver.blabla.local ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mailserver.blabla.local [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id ZkXsQejEkDHg; Thu,  3 Nov 2016 12:04:10 +0100 (CET)
Received: from [192.168.2.196] (unknown [192.168.2.1])
    by mailserver.blabla.local (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 512A8741B70;
    Thu,  3 Nov 2016 12:03:31 +0100 (CET)
To: Migra MV <sender@domain.de>
From: IntegrationsFachDienst Migration MM <sender@domain.de>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Aktuell:_=c3=9cber_200_Bildungsma=c3=9fnahmen_auch_f?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=c3=bcr_Zugewanderte_in_ganz_M-V?=
Message-ID: <045abb9f-de00-bdc5-cede-01e338164930@migra-mv.local>
Date: Thu, 3 Nov 2016 12:03:51 +0100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/45.2.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------55D5725BF82BAD7B1782022E"
```

Why are we getting this error and aren't the messages sent? In fact, most of the messages are send without problems. Could this be an error from the recipient?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same as [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/509469/1867). Either the client or the server is not following the protocol correctly.